# ListView + ItemTemplate conditional binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview which one of the  is binding my user's photo image. However, if the <%#Eval("Photo") %> is a null value which means the user hasn't uploaded a photo yet, I want to display a default one which path is

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_DEFAULTPROFILEPHOTO_PATH"]%>
```

This is the line here, it doesn't throw any error but right now the images are all blank. Anyone can assist? Thanks.

```
<a href="ProfilePage.aspx?user=<%#Eval("UserName") %>" target="_parent"><img src="<%#Eval("Photo") %> != null ? <%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_PROFILEPHOTO_PATH"]%>/<%#Eval("UserName") %>/<%#Eval("Photo") %> : <%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_DEFAULTPHOTO_PATH"]%>" class="tipTip" title="<%#Eval("Name") %>" style="border: 1px solid #B6B6B6; height: 55px; width: 50px" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: Do you want to display an image or a link to the image in the listview?

Comment: I need to display the image in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source binding is incorrect, try this:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img alt="profilePic" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("Photo") != null ? String.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_PROFILEPHOTO_PATH"].ToString(),Eval("UserName"),Eval("Photo")) : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_DEFAULTPHOTO_PATH"].ToString() %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**Code behind (recreated on my side for testing) :**

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            lvImages.DataSource = new List<MyImage>
            {
                new MyImage{UserName="Deni",Photo="pic1.jpg"},
                new MyImage{UserName="Chad",Photo="pic2.jpg"},
                new MyImage{Photo=null},
            };
            lvImages.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

public class MyImage
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

**Image structure of the site:**

[image]

**Web.config :**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="USER_PROFILEPHOTO_PATH" value="~/Images"/>
    <add key="USER_DEFAULTPHOTO_PATH" value="~/Images/pic3.png"/>
  </appSettings>
```